# Issue in date time picker

Tags: jquery, datetime, datetimepicker, datetime-format

I am using jquery date time picker to select date and time in one field.
When i am selecting 01/18/2017 11:00 AM it shows 01/18/2017 11:01 AM. Is there any way to fix this issue.[image]

```
  function attachDateTimePickers(div) {
if ($().datetimepicker == undefined) {
    loadFilesAndExecuteCallback(['js/jquery.datetimepicker.js', 'css/jquery.datetimepicker.css'], function() {
        attachDateTimePickers(div);
    });
    return;
}

$(div).find(".date").datetimepicker({
    format : 'm/d/Y h:m A',
    formatTime : 'g:i A',
    formatDate : 'm/d/Y',
    timepicker:true,
    datepicker:true,
    validateOnBlur : false,
});
```

}

Comment: What have you use to display datetimepicker(code)?

Comment: what you have tried?

Comment: @SanjayPatel $(div).find(".date").datetimepicker({
        format : 'm/d/Y h:m A',
        formatTime : 'g:i A',
        formatDate : 'm/d/Y',
        timepicker:true,
        datepicker:true,
        validateOnBlur : false
    });  i tried this

Comment: jquery version/CDN and Html code please....

Comment: @SanjayPatel jquery version 1.9.1

Comment: @SanjayPatel <input
           type="text" id="txtPatientMyAppointmentsDate" class="date form-control input-sm mandatory" /> and i pass text box to above function